# smooth in one direction, nowhere differentiable in the other

Tags: examples-counterexamples

Can anyone think of an example $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $u$ is smooth in $x_1$ but nowhere differentiable in $x_2$?

Comment: What about (the direct product of a constant function and the Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function) x a bump function?